# How can I eliminate the lines in TreeView while keeping all arrows

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView which I am skinning using the `SetWindowsTheme()` pinvoke, however I am unable to remove the tree lines that appear.

I do not wish to do 'Owner' drawn as I believe that would be the equivalent of taking an 18-wheeler truck to deliver one taco (overkill).

What is a clean, quick way to eliminate the Tree forks while keeping the expansion arrows. (I need to keep the arrows on the root nodes as well)

[image: tree arrows]

should look like :

[image: treeview no forks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourTreeView.ShowLines = false;
yourTreeView.ShowPlusMinus = true;
```

[image]

Not sure if this will show up as you wish under your theme, though.

Comment: Thank you.  Overlooked the obvious.  Was only seeing `ShowPlusMinus` and `ShowRootLines`, the latter of which enabled visiblity of the root expanded/collapsed icons.     :)

Comment: To answer "Not sure if this will show up as you wish under your theme, though." -- yes, it worked perfectly  :)